# Wrong items of ListView selected when comparing Strings

Tags: android, listview

Adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Category> categories){
        super(context, 0, categories);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Category category = getItem(position);

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_game_choose_category, parent, false);
        }

        TextView categoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        TextView categorySubtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categorySub);
        TextView categoryQuestionsCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryQuestionsCount);

        categoryName.setText(category.categoryName); // Populate
        categorySubtext.setText(category.categorySubtext);
        categoryQuestionsCount.setText(category.categoryQuestionsCount);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Category {
   public Category(String categoryName,
                    String categoryId,
                    String categoryParentId,
                    String categoryQuestionsCount,
                    String categorySubtext) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryParentId = categoryParentId;
        this.categoryQuestionsCount = categoryQuestionsCount;
        this.categorySubtext = categorySubtext;
    }
}
```

I wanted to hide TextViews that are empty, so inside the `getView` method in Adapter i wrote something like:

```
if(category.categorySubtext.equals("")) { categorySubtext.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
```

But suddenly, even the items that HAD the "categorySubtext" filled, got called by this clause! And after some scrolling through my ListView, ALL the items had visibility:gone.

I also tried calling `category.categorySubtext.isEmpty()` or `category.categorySubtext.trim().equalsIgnoreCase()` - every time I get the same behavior.

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried if(category.categorySubtext.equals("")||category.categorySubtext.isEmpty()) { categorySubtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); } ??

Comment: @M.Mariscal I have. Unfortunately, it wasn't the case. Check out the answer below. Thanks for responding though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views are reused for different rows/items of the ListView and you never set them to visible.

Use something like this instead:

```
categorySubtext.setVisibility(
         category.categorySubtext.isEmpty() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE
     );
```

Comment: Thanks! It did indeed work, I get it now why it doesn't work my way. I also didn't know you can use syntax like that, lol. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Did you mean the ternary `? :` operator? a shorthand for if-else in many languages.

Comment: I knew this one before, but I didn't know you can use if else clause inside calling a method. I thought you have to directly put an argument in there, f.e. `View.GONE` - haven't seen this one before, but looks very useful!

Comment: Ah OK, it's an "expression" (something that evaluates to a value). Useful at times, confusing at times. Remember to make it easy to read! Can also make it somewhat harder to debug easily. On it's own line it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

try to add an `else` statement that changes visiblity to `visible`